# Galois-action on spectral sequence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, galois-representations, spectral-sequences

Let $X_\bullet\to S$ be a proper surjective hypercover of a $k$-scheme by smooth proper $k$-schemes. This gives a proper surjective hypercover $X'_\bullet\to S_{\bar{k}}$ where $X'_n:=X_n\times_k \bar{k}$ and thus for a (pro-)étale sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $S_\bar{k}$ we get a spectral sequence
$$E_1^{p,q}:H^{q}(X'_p,\mathcal{F}\vert_{X'_p})\Rightarrow H^{p+q}(S_\bar{k},\mathcal{F}).$$
My question is if this is Galois-equivariant. I'd naively would think so, but it is not explicitly mentioned in sources I've seen, which makes me sceptical. This would be quite convenient even if we don't care for the Galois-action per se, but would also give "early" degeneration since there are only trival morphisms between representations of unequal weight, right? If the spectral sequence is not Galois-equivariant, can we fix it by Tate-twists (which is what we have to do to for the Hodge-Tate decomposition)?

Comment: Yes it is Galois-equivariant because the construction of the descent spectral sequence is natural in the proper surjective hypercover, as can be immediately verified from the construction.

Comment: @DenisNardin that's a good answer, you should make it official :-)

Comment: I'll accept it as soon as you do, apologies for the question, I was just confused that I couldn't find a reference...